# How to sort n elements in range[1, logn**logn] within O(nloglogn) time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, counting

I am having a problem in my algorithm class. The problem states:

> Assume you are given an array of n integers in the range{1,...,logn**logn}. Show how to sort this array in time O(nloglogn).

This is a weekly assignment, this week we mainly work on heap sort and counting sort. Well at first glance I see there is a range, so I tried counting sort....But the range is too big. Counting sort is O(n+k), where k is the range. Here logn**logn is bigger than the required nloglogn. So I feel lost. 
So, for sure we can not use comparison sort because that's bounded below O(n logn). Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the exponent affecting only n, or the whole log(n)?

Comment: Following up on @conditionalMethod comment, is this log(n^(log(n)) (= log(n)^2) or (log(n))^(log(n)) ? If the range is too large for counting sort, then you can use radix sort.

Comment: Hi. It is log(n) to the power of log(n). [log(n)] ^ [log(n)]

Comment: @rcgldr Hi. I tried radix sort, this in the end gives me O(n*logn*loglogn*) . But not O(n*loglogn). I am still working on it ,trying to find a way out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *n* is an integer such that there is an integer *x* such that *a* = logx(*n*) and *b* = logx(*a*) = logx(logx(*n*)) are integers, then using *n* as the radix base, it will take *b* radix passes for time complexity O(n b) = O(n log(log(n)). Doing the math:

```
x^a = n
x^b = a
a^a = range
n^b = range of radix sort
n^b = (x^a)^b = x^(a b) = x^(a logx(a)) = x^(logx(a^a)) = a^a
```

example

```
n = 65536
x = 2
a = 16
b = 4
2^16 = n
2^4 = 16
a^a = range = 2^64
n^b = range of radix sort = (2^16)^4 = 2^(16 · 4) = 2^64
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how you compute the radix. Say you use n as basis. So we want to know the radix such that---> n^radix = max number in range = logn to the power of logn.

Comment: Then I tried to solve radix. take log both side. radix * n = logn * log_base n_(logn)

Comment: But I don't see how to come up with log(log(n)) in the end. Thanks

Comment: @chicago - I showed this in the math part. a = logx(n). b = logx(logx(n)) = logx(a) = number of radix passes. Then on the last line of the math part, I showed that range (max+1-min) = n^b = ... = a^a = logx(n)^logx(n). So with b = logx(logx(n)) radix passes of n elements moved per radix pass, time complexity is O(n log(log(n))).